# Apply authentication to media files

Tags: media-library

We are using Sitecore 9.3 with SXA. I have some pdf files stored in the media library in sitecore. These files can be downloaded by users after logging in to the site.

There is a security finding that these pdf files are getting downloaded even by anonymous users if they paste the link to these media items directly in the browser.

How can I make sure that these files can be downloaded only by authenticated users of the site?

Further details -

1. Sitecore 9.3 with SXA
2. MVC
3. Users are being authenticated through Azure AD B2C. Basically there is an internal system created as a wrapper around Azure AD B2C. So, using that for authentication.

Comment: There is a similar question raised before. Please verify if this helps for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65147358/sitecore-how-to-prevent-the-anonymous-users-to-access-media-library-items-in-s

Comment: Can you add more details here? What Sitecore version? Headless or MVC? How are your users being authenticated on the site?

Comment: @RichardSeal Added more details in the description.

Comment: In Sitecore, you can create a custom media folder template inherited from "/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Media folder" and set the security permissions on this template for anonymous and authenticated users. You can then create a secure folder and upload the PDF files to this folder. Also there is a tutorial regarding to Azure  https://sam-solutions.us/azure-ad-b2c-tutorial-how-to-authenticate-in-sitecore-via-azure/. Hope it helps